# naming tables in many to many relationships laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-migrations

I concerned about auto naming tables in many-to-many Laravel relationship.

for example:

```
Schema::create('feature_product', function (Blueprint $table) {}
```

when change the table name to:

```
Schema::create('product_feature', function (Blueprint $table) {}
```

I have an error in my relationship.

What's the matter with `product_feature`?

Comment: What is the exact error? Also what database are you using?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Laravel's naming convention for pivot tables is snake_cased model names in alphabetical order separated by an underscore. So, if one model is `Feature`, and the other model is `Product`, the pivot table will be `feature_product`.

You are free to use any table name you want (such as `product_feature`), but you will then need to specify the name of the pivot table in the relationship. This is done using the second parameter to the `belongsToMany()` function.

```
// in Product model
public function features()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Feature', 'product_feature');
}

// in Feature model
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_feature');
}
```

You can read more about [many to many relationships in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: Could you provide reference?

Comment: @MohammadAliAkbari I added a link to the docs. Also corrected a slight assumption about model and table names.

Comment: Does it make sense to name the pivots in a singular format in sql database?