# Using multiple joins in a Laravel statement overrides values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I am trying to create a Laravel statement which should return the correct values per user for amount of answers and amount of questions like so:

```
$users = User::join('user_answers', 'users.id', '=', 'users_answers.user_id')
        ->join('user_questions', 'users.id', '=', 'user_questions.user_id')
        ->select(
            'users.id',
            'users.username',
            DB::raw('COUNT(user_answers.user_id) AS answers'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(user_questions.user_id) AS questions')
        )
        ->groupBy('users.id');
```

**NOTE: The groupBy is required for it to work because it is used in DataTables, otherwise it will show only one row.**

When I attempted to:

```
dd($users->first());
```

What I got is this:

[image: Example]

As you can see, the values are for some reason the same for questions and answers, and are incorrect. I imagine there is some kind of overlapping with the joins.

**For instance, if I remove one of the joins, and leave one of the columns only, the numbers show correctly, like so:**

[image: Example 2]

I am honestly quite lost here, would appreciate some help.

Thank you!

Comment: The counts are multiplied (1412 * 5 = 7060), because you join unrelated questions and answers.

Comment: I think you should not use  `DB::raw()` in select you can append where clause for that.

Comment: Instead of join, db::raw() & select, I would utilize collection for this approach

Comment: @senty Fetching 1412 answers into a collection just to get the count? This will speed up global warming ;-)

Comment: Hi, I cannot use collections instead of select() and raw DB since then it would not be sortable (using DataTables). @PaulSpiegel could you elaborate please and how I could avoid this?

Comment: if you're using datatables and you can separately write query for that particular column just `->editColumn('questionCounts',User $user){ //return counts}`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, well, no, just the count. `['id', username', 'answers', 'questions']`. `User::get()->each(function($colEl) { // Do count() queries here and push to collection }`

Comment: Fast and "dirty" fix would be `COUNT(DISTINCT user_answers.id) AS answers`

Comment: Is this what you mean @ViperTecPro? ..editColumn('answers', function ($query) {
    return $query->join('user_answers', 'users.id', '=', 'user_answers.user_id')->groupBy('users.id')->count();
   })

Comment: @PaulSpiegel That actually worked, thanks! Could you explain why this would be a "dirty" fix though? :D

Comment: @MichaelNaidis "dirty" because you let the DB do more work than needed. The propper SQL way would be to use correlated subqueries in SELECT instead of using JOINs.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't use *Eloquent* for a long time, so I don't know if there is an "eloquent" way to do this with a single query. But in SQL I would use correlated subqueries in the SELECT clause:

```
$users = User::select(
            'users.id',
            'users.username',
            DB::raw('(
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM user_answers
                WHERE users_answers.user_id = users.id
            ) AS answers'),
            DB::raw('(
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM user_questions
                WHERE user_questions.user_id = users.id
            ) AS questions'),
        );
```

Comment: I'll look into an option if it is possible to construct this via Eloquent. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelNaidis See the other answer - that's the way.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [Eloquent's relational methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) in order to construct this.  There's even a `withCount()` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) that you can use to construct your query.

The relational methods would be something like:

```
public function answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Answer::class);
}
```

One thing to keep in mind with pivot table naming is that [Laravel expects the tables to be named alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897444/naming-tables-in-many-to-many-relationships-laravel).  So for a [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) it would expect the pivot to be named `answer_user`.  However, you can define a custom pivot table name in the Model's relational method.

Once you set up the relational methods in your model, then you should be able to construct a query similar to the below:

```
User::withCount(['answers', 'questions'])->get();
```

Once you get that working you can constrain with select statements.

Comment: That's what I meant with "eloquent way" in my answer. It will probably generate the exactly same query using just a one-liner.

Comment: I liked where you were going with yours... but ORMs :)

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about withCount().

Comment: Pretty neat solution here! Thanks for the `withCount()`